# How to solve error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'" with MQTT Python Client

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I installed the MQTT broker(Mosquitto) on my Raspberry and installed the client (Paho Client Python). I tried to start my client, but I have this error when running my file.

```
  File "client_mqtt.py", line 38, in <module>
    client = mqtt.client()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

My complete file is that

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sys

#definicoes: 
Broker            = "localhost"
username          = "mosquitto"
password          = "mqtt"
PortaBroker       = 1883
KeepAliveBroker   = 60
client_name       = "Local"

topic_casa = "casa" 
topic_mcu  = "mcu" 


#Callback - conexao ao broker realizada
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("[STATUS] Conectado ao Broker. Resultado de conexao: "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic_mcu)
    client.subscribe(topic_casa)
    

#Callback - mensagem recebida do broker
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    MensagemRecebida = str(msg.payload)
    
    print("[MSG RECEBIDA] Topico: "+msg.topic+" / Mensagem: "+MensagemRecebida)


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        print("Unexpected disconnection.")  

#programa principal:
try:
        print("[STATUS] Inicializando MQTT...")
        #inicializa MQTT:
        client = mqtt.Client()
        client.username_pw_set(username, password)
        client.on_connect     = on_connect
        client.on_message     = on_message
        client.on_disconnect  = on_disconnect

        client.connect(Broker, PortaBroker, KeepAliveBroker)
        client.loop_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "\nCtrl+C pressionado, encerrando aplicacao e saindo..."
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't match the code you've posted.

The error implies that you are using `mqtt.client()` not `mqtt.Client()`

Comment: hardillb is correct.  line 38 of your snippet correctly says `client = mqtt.Client()`  But the error message you quote says `client = mqtt.client()`  That code would give the error message.  I know because I'm here for the same reason :-)  I changed `mqtt.client()` to `mqtt.Client()` and got mine working.

Answer (score -2):

i have same issue,

```
   File "random.py", line 3, in <module>
     import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

It happened because my current filename is random.py. Try to rename your client_mqtt.py, maybe it can fix your issue.